# method authenticate misssing from User model using secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, railstutorial.org

Using Rails 3.1.3. I'm using the method of password authentication presented in railscast 270 to place the call to "has_secure_password":

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end
```

It works except for one extremely puzzling issue. The documentation states to use

user.authenticate("notright")

But I can't see where the authenticate method is declared. I looked in secure_password, and a seemingly equivalent method is:

```
  # Returns self if the password is correct, otherwise false.
  def get_logged_in_user(unencrypted_password)
    if BCrypt::Password.new(password_digest) == unencrypted_password
      self
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

Note, I'm trying to convert the example from the railstutorial.org (really wonderful), so there was quite a bit I had to change, and there could be something in my application that is conflicting. For example, I had previously had this line:

```
attr_accessor :password
```

And that prevented the declaration of password= from ever being called in secure_password, resulting in the db column for password_digest being nil. Removing this line fixed this problem.

Update: I created a brand new rails app with 3.1.3, and confirmed that the simplest case of running these two commands results in the error:

> > u = User.create(:username => "a", :password => "foobar", :password_confirmation => "foobar")
> >        (0.1ms)  BEGIN
> >       SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`created_at`, `password_digest`, `updated_at`, `username`) VALUES ('2011-12-21 05:18:17', '$2a$10$BbwHbq1bGwvQRgE0xK28VeP8K/lwY.VfLaLsMSs6ogNa1DucephnK', '2011-12-21 05:18:17', 'a')
> >        (42.6ms)  COMMIT
> >
> > u.authenticate("foobar")
> >     u.authenticate("foobar")
> >     NoMethodError: undefined method `authenticate' for #<User:0xa26e4cc>
> >         from /home/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@testapp/gems/activemodel-3.1.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:385:in`method_missing'
> >         from /home/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@testapp/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:60:in `method_missing'
> >         from (irb):4
> >         from /home/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@testapp/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in`start'
> >         from /home/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@testapp/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
> >         from /home/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@testapp/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in`'
> >         from /home/justin/j/RubymineProjects/auth/script/rails:6:in `require'
> >         from /home/justin/j/RubymineProjects/auth/script/rails:6:in`'
> >         from -e:1:in `load'
> >         from -e:1:in`'

UPDATE:
This is definitely some sort of issue with ruby 1.9.3. I tried the same gems out on 1.9.2 and I have no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an authenticate method as follows ([source](https://gist.github.com/raw/950378/6248be4172e4dd4f6779d0b7f4b978f9a73c9788/user_model_eteubert.rb)) solved it for me.

I'm using ruby 1.9.3 as well. I've not tried 1.9.2 as you have.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Ruby 1.9.3 solve the issue.